# Load test application where documents require electronic signature

Tags: jmeter, electronic-signature

How can I load test web application that requires to sign a document using an electronic signature? Is it possible with JMeter?

In a web application there is a form, then data sent by the user in form create a document with is then signed using a qualified electronic signature

Answer (score 0):

The generic answer is **yes**, from JMeter's perspective electronic signature is yet another [HTTP Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) so you will need to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) and configure it to send the relevant header containing the signature.

If you're lucky enough you will be able to record the call from the browser using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and successfully replay it.

If not - it is still possible to generate the signature given you know the algorithm or have a relevant [SDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) allowing programmatic signature of the HTTP requests using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).